# How do I limit the number of digits from 6 to 4 in JS? (imput field type number and readonly)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, calculator

I'm trying to build a calorie calculator for my website. Fields give me results like this 0.000.000. I am trying to solve the problem and display only 4 digits, like below for example: 0.000

I have no idea what the function is, I'm a fan and have no programming skills. Please Help!

https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/89wtnxj4/273/

```
<!--Input Field-->
<label class="mts-label">Peso</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="3" id="weight" name"weight1" placeholder="es: 70Kg"/>

<label class="mts-label">Altezza</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="3" id="height" name"height1" placeholder="es: 170cm"/>

<label class="mts-label">Età</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="age" name"age1" placeholder="es: 25 anni"/>

<label class="mts-label">Bodyfat in %</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="bodyfat" name"bodyfat1" placeholder="es: 15%"/>

<div class="mts-label">Sesso</div>

<!--Radio Button Sex-->
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexuomo">Uomo</label>
  </div>

  <div class="mts-radio-button1">
    <input type="radio" id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexdonna">Donna</label>
  </div>
  
  <!--Radio Activity Level-->
  <br>
 
  <label class="mts-label">Attività lavorativa</label>
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="leggero" name="radiosa" value="1.2" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="leggero">Leggero</label>
  </div>
  
   <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="attivo" name="radiosa" value="1.375" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="attivo">Attivo</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="allenato" name="radiosa" value="1.55" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="allenato">Allenato</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="Mattivo" name="radiosa" value="1.75" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="Mattivo">Molto Attivo</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="Eattivo" name="radiosa" value="1.9" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="Eattivo">Estremamente Attivo</label>
  </div>

<!---BMR Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Mifflin St Jeor Formula</label><br>


<div id="bmr-sexuomo" hidden>
<label class="mts-label">Male</label><br>
<input type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_man" name="bmr_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<div id="bmr-sexdonna" hidden>
<label class="mts-label">Female</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_woman" name="bmr_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Mifflin St Jeor Formula</label><br>
<div id="MifflinMale" hidden> 
<label class="mts-label">Male</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_man" name="tdee_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal Uomo" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<div id="MifflinFemale" hidden> 
<label class="mts-label">Female</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_woman" name="tdee_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal donna" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_katch" name="bmr_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_katch" name="tdee_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_cunningham" name="bmr_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_cunningham" name="tdee_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---Calc & Reset Button--->
<br>
<button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Re-Calculate</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

---

```
<!--Input Field-->
<label class="mts-label">Peso</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="3" id="weight" name"weight1" placeholder="es: 70Kg"/>

<label class="mts-label">Altezza</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="3" id="height" name"height1" placeholder="es: 170cm"/>

<label class="mts-label">Età</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="age" name"age1" placeholder="es: 25 anni"/>

<label class="mts-label">Bodyfat in %</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="bodyfat" name"bodyfat1" placeholder="es: 15%"/>

<div class="mts-label">Sesso</div>

<!--Radio Button Sex-->
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexuomo">Uomo</label>
  </div>

  <div class="mts-radio-button1">
    <input type="radio" id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexdonna">Donna</label>
  </div>
  
  <!--Radio Activity Level-->
  <br>
 
  <label class="mts-label">Attività lavorativa</label>
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="leggero" name="radiosa" value="1.2" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="leggero">Leggero</label>
  </div>
  
   <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="attivo" name="radiosa" value="1.375" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="attivo">Attivo</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="allenato" name="radiosa" value="1.55" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="allenato">Allenato</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="Mattivo" name="radiosa" value="1.75" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="Mattivo">Molto Attivo</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="Eattivo" name="radiosa" value="1.9" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="Eattivo">Estremamente Attivo</label>
  </div>

<!---BMR Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Mifflin St Jeor Formula</label><br>


<div id="bmr-sexuomo" hidden>
<label class="mts-label">Male</label><br>
<input type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_man" name="bmr_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<div id="bmr-sexdonna" hidden>
<label class="mts-label">Female</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_woman" name="bmr_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Mifflin St Jeor Formula</label><br>
<div id="MifflinMale" hidden> 
<label class="mts-label">Male</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_man" name="tdee_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal Uomo" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<div id="MifflinFemale" hidden> 
<label class="mts-label">Female</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_woman" name="tdee_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal donna" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_katch" name="bmr_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_katch" name="tdee_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_cunningham" name="bmr_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_cunningham" name="tdee_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---Calc & Reset Button--->
<br>
<button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Re-Calculate</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is the [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method?

Comment: I don't think I know how to use it well, I've read something, but how do I implement it correctly in my code?

Comment: I added the tofixed method, now however, the numbers are displayed like this 0000.00 instead of 0.000 There are still 6 digits left while I'm trying to have only 4 (thousands + hundreds).

Comment: See Skoua's answer below. I was going to suggest to use a combination of [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to round off the number to get rid of the decimals and then apply `toLocaleString('it-IT')` to the result of that rounded number giving you your thousand's separator back. But what he suggests is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `toLocaleString` that you don't want digits:

```
document.getElementById('tdee_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 } + " Kcal";
```

Here's the doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: That's very neat - I was just typing out a long answer on how he could remedy the situation but your answer is simpler than mine was. This is interesting to know. Didn't realise that you could pass an options object to toLocaleString.

Comment: Grazie per l'intervento. Funziona correttamente ma ho notato che mancava una parentesi di chiusura, per cui lascio qui il codice corretto per chiunque fosse interessato. `document.getElementById('tdee_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 } ) + " Kcal";`